# Ran power through a USB port- am I out of luck?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, power, acer-aspire

I'd like to preface this by saying I'm an idiot.

Long story short, I stuck my Acer Aspire V's power cable into one of its USB ports and the computer unceremoniously died. Plugging it in shows no signs of life, not even the charging light. The brick doesn't have any light and I don't have anything to test whether it's still putting out power, so while I'm fairly sure it's the computer that's broken (seeing as it won't turn on), I can't be positive.

Is there any chance that my laptop isn't completely dead? I know some things have fuses that take time to reset, but I have no idea here. I have an extended warranty through my credit card, but I'd prefer to get this working without sending it anywhere if possible.

Comment: My old laptop's charging port was where the USB port is on this one, and the charger plug is small enough to fit, so muscle memory took over. Also, as mentioned, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but it's very probable the the motherboard is broken. And maybe also the power brick.

Usually there are fuses on the USB port but their main function is to protect from a overcurrent.

Send the laptop to repair.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug everything and remove the battery. Hold the power button on the laptop for 10 seconds with no battery and nothing plugged in. Then try plugging the power cable in (preferably the correct port) and powering the laptop on with no battery or any peripherals.

Comment: There's no removable battery on this model. I'll try cracking it open, but since it's under warranty if i see a sticker I'm gonna stop.

Comment: No dice. I managed to get the battery unplugged and followed the steps, but it's still not powering up or even acknowledging that there's power. I did discover a pinhole on the bottom that seems to act as a battery reset, but that didn't work either. I appreciate the effort, though.